# PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator: Can you call getSubIterator() with a depth greater than your current depth?

Tags: php, spl

When recursively iterating using an instance of `\RecursiveIteratorIterator` is it expected behaviour that in looking for a sub iterator of a depth greater than your current depth, it always returns `null`?

Please see: [RecursiveIteratorIterator::getSubIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getsubiterator.php)

> public RecursiveIterator RecursiveIteratorIterator::getSubIterator ([
>   int $level ] )

Example:

```
$innerIterator = new \RecursiveArrayIterator([/*a recursive array*/]);
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($innerIterator);

foreach ($iterator as $value) {
    $depth       = $iterator->getDepth();
    $parentDepth = $depth - 1;
    $childDepth  = $depth + 1;
    // returns \RecursiveArrayIterator
    $iterator->getSubIterator($depth);
    // returns null first iteration and \RecursiveArrayIterator thereafter
    $iterator->getSubIterator($parentDepth);
    // always returns null...should it?
    $iterator->getSubIterator($childDepth);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RecursiveIteratorIterator::getSubIterator()` method's source code is short enough to be posted here, and is as good a place as any to find an answer.

```
/* {{{ proto RecursiveIterator RecursiveIteratorIterator::getSubIterator([int level])
   The current active sub iterator or the iterator at specified level */
SPL_METHOD(RecursiveIteratorIterator, getSubIterator)
{
    spl_recursive_it_object   *object = (spl_recursive_it_object*)zend_object_store_get_object(getThis() TSRMLS_CC);
    long  level = object->level;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "|l", &level) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }
    if (level < 0 || level > object->level) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }
    RETURN_ZVAL(object->iterators[level].zobject, 1, 0);
} /* }}} */
```

<sup>— From the [PHP 5.5.14 source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.5.14/ext/spl/spl_iterators.c#L680).</sup>

The key part for this question is the `if` statement:

```
if (level < 0 || level > object->level) {
    RETURN_NULL();
}
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory, but it is saying:

*If the specified level is less than zero, or **greater than** the current object's level, return **null**.*

Comment: Makes sense, we can't assume the recursive iterator has iterated far enough down the recursive tree to know what the next sub iterator looks like.